# Configuración xdebug en vagrant homestead por proyecto

Tags: php, laravel, xdebug

Estoy tratando de que xdebug funcione en mi proyecto que usa como server una máquina homestead enlazada al mismo.

Esta fue creada por medio de `composer require laravel/homestead --dev` pero no se si el host está bien, he probado varias veces y no entra en el debugger.

Teniendo en cuenta que se conecta de distinta manera a si la máquina estuviera enlazada pero no mediante la forma que yo describo sino creando la máquina a parte con `vagrant box add laravel/homestead` y `git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git ~/Homestead`.

Sigo sin entender si se conecta a la dirección de la máquina virtual 10.0.2.2 o si se conecta a 127.0.0.1 por ser la máquina local al proyecto.

Aquí está mi configuración:

```
[xdebug]
; Enable xdebug extension module
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=10.0.2.2
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.idekey="sublime.xdebug"
```